# Google Query, Return GroupBy even with Sum 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

Given the following sample query with Col A being Dates and Col B being Numbers:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C, "SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE (C = 'Www' OR C = 'ccC') GROUP BY A",1)
```

How would you get the result to display the next GROUP BY A even when the SUM(B) is = NULL, and have the NULL display 0, like an ISNULL. In T-SQL there is a way to do this but it does not work with Google. Anyone know?

Desired result:

```html
 <table border="1" style="width:20%">
  <tr>
    <td>1/1/02</td>
    <td>5</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1/2/02</td>
    <td>0</td>
    
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1/3/02</td>
    <td>5</td>
    
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1/4/02</td>
    <td>10</td>
    
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1/5/02</td>
    <td>0</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think that there could be a problem with the source data. Please add a sample source data and include the error message that you get.

Comment: I have the answer from a man named Chris Hicks on the google spreadsheet forum. Not sure if I should post it myself as the answer or if there is a way I can give him credit for it? It ended up being a combination of a query with a spreadsheet function.

Comment: You could write the answer here, just include the proper attribution. See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer by Chris Hick](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/Ct4SoJv5RjU/fholBRgZAQAJ)

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:A,ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Sheet1!C:C="Www")+(Sheet1!C:C="ccC"),Sheet1!B:B,0)),Sheet1!C:C}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1",1)`